# Strange "stutter" in box2D on different android devices

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, box2d

I'm developing an engine and a game at the same time in C++ and I'm using box2D for the physics back end. I'm testing on different android devices and on 2 out of 3 devices, the game runs fine and so do the physics. However, on my galaxy tab 10.1 I'm sporadically getting a sort of "stutter". Here is a youtube video demonstrating:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSbd8vX9FC0

The first device the game is running on is an Xperia Play... the second device is a Galaxy Tab 10.1. Needless to say the Galaxy tab has much better hardware than the Xperia Play, yet Box2D is lagging at random intervals for random lengths of time. The code for both machines is exactly the same. Also, the rest of the engine/game is not actually lagging. The entire time, it's running at solid 60 fps. So this "stuttering" seems to be some kind of delay or glitch in actually reading values from box2D.

The sprites you see moving check to see if they have an attached physical body at render time and set their positional values based on the world position of the physical body. So it seems to be in this specific process that box2D is seemingly out of sync with the rest of the application. Quite odd. I realize it's a long shot but I figured I'd post it here anyway to see if anyone had ideas... since I'm totally stumped. Thanks for any input in advance!

Oh, P.S. I am using a fixed time step since that seems to be the most commonly suggested solution for things like this. I moved to a fixed time step while developing this on my desktop, I ran into a similar issue just more severe and the fixed step was the solution. Also like I said the game is running steady at 60 fps, which is controlled by a low latency timer so I doubt simple lag is the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Have your tried outputting the time between physics steps, maybe there is a bug in your code somewhere causing them to be irregular?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are only ever giving a literal float value such as 1/60.0 to Box2D's Step() function for the time step length? And you are calling this 60 times per second for sure?

Comment: @iforce2d yes, at initialization I set up a float of 1/60 and restrict my max global FPS to 60 and this is all I ever pass to the step() method.

Comment: @tm1rbrt I'll do that and get back to you... I didn't bother because I assume that it is definitely the physics code lagging out anyway so tracing out the step time would only confirm the suspicion. Thanks everyone for the suggestions I'll update later.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with accessing system time in C/C++ with the NDK. It's supposed to be low latency but it seems with different versions of android, that is hit and miss. I call it a bug because something like this should be consistent on all platforms. After all, if you can rely on getting accurate system time, that's an issue. See my comments on Ovidiu's question for more. I may post an answer of my own just to give more details + a work around.

Comment: Sigh sorry, allow me to correct my terminology. By "low latency timer" what I REALLY meant was, high resolution timer. Sorry about the confusion all. I need sleep.

Comment: Restricting to a max of 60fps is not the same as calling step() 60 times a second. If you set up a simple integer counter and increment it after each step() do you really get say, 600 steps after 10 seconds? I don't know about android timers but the typical timer in iPhone is a single thread runloop timer which just checks on every pass through the main loop whether the timer should have fired by now, which merely guarantees that you will not get more than 60fps.

Comment: I'm not sure we're quite talking about the same thing. My main Step method is called as many times as the android device is permitted to call it in a second. Within that step method I'm using a high resolution timer to check the delay between render calls to ensure that it is consistent with the delay I would expect at 60 FPS. If the condition passes, I call render() and step on my physics world. Works flawlessly on windows. Doing some more research it seems to be that my timer class is flawed when running in a linux environment.

Comment: I'm in the process of rewriting the timer class to use C++11's chrono package, which is supposed to be guaranteed to select the highest resolution timer on the system you're deployed to. If that is successful I'll post an answer and provide my code. I was considering just doing away with the FPS throttling code on android but I can't have any guarantee that every device in the world has as a 60 hz refresh rate.

Comment: I see. One of these days I will do some Android/NDK stuff myself so I will be able to offer more than just wild speculation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments here, this came down to being a timer resolution issue. I was using a timer class which was supposed to access the highest resolution system timer, cross platform. Everything worked great, except when it came to Android, some versions worked and some versions it did not. The galaxy tab 10.1 was one such case.

I ended up re-writing my `getSystemTime()` method to use a new addition to C++11 called `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`. This also worked great (everywhere but Android)... except it has yet to be implemented in any NDK for android. It is supposed to be implemented in version 5 of the crystax NDK R7, which at the time of this post is 80% complete.

I did some research into various methods of accessing the system time or something by which I could base a reliable timer on the NDK side, but what it comes down to is that these various methods are not supported on all platforms. I've went through the painful process of writing my own engine from scratch simply so that I could support every version of android, so betting on methods that are inconsistently implemented is nonsensical.

**The only sensible solution for anyone facing this problem, in my opinion, is to simply abandon the idea of implementing such code on the NDK side**. I'm going to do this on the Java end instead, since thus far in all my tests this has been sufficiently reliable across all devices that I've tested on. More on that here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189515/Androng-a-Pong-clone-for-Android#Gettinghigh-resolutiontimingfromAndroid7

**Update**

I have now implemented my proposed solution, to do timing on the java side and it has worked. I also discovered that handling any relatively large number, regardless of data type (a number such as the nano seconds from calling the monotonic clock) in the NDK side also results in serious lagging on some versions of android. As such I've optimized this as much as possible by passing around a pointer to the system time, to ensure we're not passing-by-copy.

One last thing too, my statement that calling the monotonic clock from the NDK side is unreliable is however, it would seem, false. From the Android docks on [System.nanoTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html),

> ...and System.nanoTime(). This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic,
> and is the recommended basis for the general purpose interval timing
> of user interface events, performance measurements, and anything else
> that does not need to measure elapsed time during device sleep.

So it would seem, if this can be trusted, that calling the clock is reliable, but as mentioned there are other issues that then arise, like handling allocating and dumping the massive number that results which alone nearly cut my framerate in half on the Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 3.2. **Ultimate conclusion:** *supporting all android devices equally is either damn near or flat out impossible and using native code seems to make it worse*.

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to game development, and you seem a lot more experienced  and it may be silly to ask, but are you using `delta time` to update your world? Altough you say you have a constant frame rate of 60 fps, maybe your frame counter calculates something wrong, and you should use `delta time` to skip some frames when the FPS is low, or your world seem to "stay behind". I am pretty sure that you are familiar with this, but I think a good example is here : [DeltaTimeExample](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=325201) altough it is a C implementation. If you need I can paste some code from my Android Projects of how I use delta time, that I've developed following this book : [Beginning Android Games](http://www.apress.com/9781430230427).

Comment: So, I haven't narrowed down exactly what the issue is yet but I do know now, thanks to you, that it is definitely a timing issue. My code uses the low latency system timer of the platform it is on for throttling FPS but I guess on different versions of android, the "low latency" portion seems hit and miss :S. I dismissed this originally as an issue because android was reporting full FPS... but then realized that my fps throttling code simply bypasses rendering when it's not "ready", which would report full FPS regardless.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going to post my own answer yet. The only reason I would post it is so I can give more information on the exact problem to other developers that come across this issue (in my answer I can post code snippets and such which would be sloppy to do in comments) but believe me if I could I would upvote your question 100X lol. This is a perfect example of why one should not be up till 5 am coding.

Comment: I am very glad that this helped you. You can post your answer/solution and accept it, so it can help others. There's no problem with me.

Comment: Thanks. Your post did help, unfortunately it's led me down a disappointing road. It turns out that trying to get a reliable clock/timer reading on the NDK side of android is impossible. I'll post more details in my answer.